# Twilio inbound call status callback

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I know I can set the status callback url when make a outbound call.
But how can I set a status callback url for an inbound call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can either set your inbound call webhook in your [Twilio Console by updating your numbers](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming). Or you can set it via the REST API by POSTing an update to your number with the `VoiceUrl` parameter set to your new URL.

That would look like this in PHP:

```
$sid = "your_account_sid"; 
$token = "your_auth_token"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$number = $client->account->incoming_phone_numbers->get("your_phone_number_sid");
$number->update(array(
    "VoiceUrl" => "http://example.com/voice"
));
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Just found there is a 'CALL STATUS CHANGES' in console, generally for both inbound and outbound calls. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @philnash.. i am using the Java api and updating the callback url for an inbound call like this - `Call.updater(pathSid).setStatusCallback(new URI(statusCallBackUrl)).update(this.twilioRestClient)` I do not get any error on this line but i am not receiving any events on my statusCallBackUrl..any help?

Comment: It's not a good idea to have this conversation in the comments of another question. Could you start a new question, tag it with "twilio" and add a bit more context and I'll try to help.